# Are there any offline blogging tools available?

Tags: software-recommendation, blog

I am looking for an application (not a browser extension) that supports offline blogging and uploading (when needed). Is there any such tool ?

I am primarily looking for compatibility with [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com/).

Comment: Tried Blogilo? It's in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @jokerdino forgot how the answer procedure work?

Comment: @jokerdino It hasn't got an update since 2010, going by http://blogilo.gnufolks.org/2010/02/blogilo-1-0-1/#more-147 Although, it should probably work. I will check and post tomorrow.

Comment: Most blogging sites allow you to post via email.  Did you check to see whether blogger allows you to post by email?

Comment: @TheLordofTime Yes, it does. I didn't get your point though.

Comment: @jokerdino It appears to be partially working. Having some authentication problems, so uploading will probably not work. I will post more later on. And the *error messages are absolutely useless*

Comment: @AshRj my point was that you could create your post as an email, send it with an email client, and then it would sit in your outbox until you have internet connectivity, when it would then send.

Comment: @AshRj is compatibility with blogger 100% required by you for software recommendations?

Comment: @TheLordofTime Thats the service that I use. Although, I wouldn't mind making this a general post for offline blogging applications **if** there isn't one already.

Answer (score 2):

**[Thingamablog](http://www.thingamablog.com/)** is an easy to use and powerful cross platform blogging tool. And when I say "easy to use" I am serious. It can be used to create localhost blogs or put them on your web server with ease. It is as powerful as wordpress, blogger, and it allow you to customize your themes with ease using html.

Unfortunately there is no more official support nor new releases but I can confirm that you can run it in at least 12.04 and probably further.

My current blog and the official Thingamablog website are yet made in Thingamablog. My blog (for demo purposes) can be reached [clicking here](http://geppettvs.x10.mx/blog).

A screenshot of thingamablog working in my 12.04 LTS is placed here. Additional information can be reached in the official website at http://www.thingamablog.com/

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Does it have offline support, though?  That'ts one of the things they're asking about.

Comment: If you host your own server yes. You can self-host it locally and upload it later via FTP. However it won't work for blogger nor wordpress services. This is a great tool for self hosting blogs. Thanks for observing that.

Comment: They do mention it needs blogger support, so you'll have to forgive the thumbs-down on your answer, but since it doesn't really do what they're asking, well...

Comment: No problem. But if you don't mind I would let this answer here just for future reference. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have an issue with leaving this here, because it was actually an "answer", just not one which answers the OP's question.  It won't be deleted, if that's your concern :)

Answer (score 1):

one of the blogging clients I have used (in GNOME) is [Drivel](http://drivel.sourceforge.net/). Though it hasn't been worked on for quite some time (2009). It still worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04. I used it for my blogger and according to its homepage it supports LiveJournal, Blogger, MovableType, Advogato, and Atom journals (systems based off these are also supported, including WordPress and Drupal). Here's a quick overview of its features (also from their website):

- The ability to post, edit, delete, and view recent entries.
- Integrated spell checking and HTML syntax highlighting.
- Off line composition and editing.
- Automatic recovery in the event of a crash.
- Journal system extensions, including LiveJournal security groups and MovableType categories.

It's not super extensive, but for most general blogging without a too fancy lay out it will be just fine. It gets out of your way and provides you with either simple formatting options or you can use raw HTML to format your blogposts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Blosxom and Pyblosxom are blogging tools that feed off a plain text file - so very unix.  Minimalist and elegant, they also resolve the offline problem.

Alas, not Blogger.  But still worth checking out if you want a simple offline way to blog, and vi (or emacs) is your editor of choice.

Comment: Downvoted because the OP still wants compatibility with blogger. Unless I missed something in the interim.

Comment: thank you for reading and repeating what I just said. Adds lots to the post.